# Detecting More than 100 Faces with the Microsoft Face - Detect API

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

The Microsoft Face - Detect with Url/Stream API detects a maximum of 100 faces from a given Image. I have a dataset of images that contain more than 100 faces in an image. Is there a work-around to detect faces > 100 from the image?

```
Up to 100 faces can be returned for an image. Faces are ranked by face rectangle size from large to small.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face/detectwithurl

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it is the limitation of this service and we can not implement more than 100 faces. You can raise a ticket on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) page to ask for this feature.